# Masking of fields in Mule

Tags: soap, esb, mule, masking

I want to be able to mask a certain field from the current message payload in Mule, when logging it to a file. The field I want to mask is a sensitive value (say account number, or social security number) in a SOAP payload. This is to eliminate security risks. However, I also need to use the value later, after masking it.

**My current approach**

I am storing the current #[payload] in a session, and then modifying the current payload to replace the sensitive data by * * * *, using an XSLT transformer. Now, I can add the payload to a log, and the sensitive data will not be shown in its entirety. Then when I need the data, I am reading it back from the session.

Something does not feel right about this method. It feels more like a workaround. Is there a better way to do masking in mule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writting to a log doesn't sound like something you have to do synchronously.

Can't you just "async" the xslt transformer and the logger? That would leave the original message untouched outside the async.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I totally overlooked the fact that writing to a log should actually be async, as it should not interrupt the current thread.
But, is this the right way to mask values? Is there any other approach?

Comment: The async will create a copy for that thread, so you don't have to keep nothing in the headers.
XSLT for masking? I've done it in the past for payloads that were just XML. I don't see a problem there. Unless you previously unmarhaled it (it won't make sense to marshall->xslt just to remove it) just remove it in your POJO.