# customize mule logger

Tags: mule, esb

In mule, when request is coming, mule automatically log complete request which contain credit card information and we dont want to log that field in payload. Can we customize payload to hide some fields or mask some fields in logging.

Comment: What you have tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: Mule does not automatically log the payload of a message. Can you paste the XML of your flow to understand what is the problem?

Comment: @VíctorRomero Yes that i know, i have added logger, we want logging in our application but when logger logs the payload we want to customize the sensitive information eg mask credit card number.

Comment: That depends on what kind of Payload you have. If it's XML i.e: leverage [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipsensitive/index.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466303/masking-of-fields-in-mule).

Answer (score 1):

If you're logging all mule categories, then the org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage will also be logged (and it contains the payload). In your logging configuration:

```
<!-- this will log all mule log messages -->   
<logger name="org.mule" level="DEBUG" />
```

If you wanna hide it, you can reduce the parent mule category level and explicitly log the ones you're interested into. For example:

```
<!-- this will log all mule log messages -->   
<logger name="org.mule" level="WARN" />
<logger name="org.mule.endpoint" level="INFO" />
<logger name="org.mule.transformer" level="INFO" />
<logger name="org.mule.session" level="DEBUG" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply regex on to your payload before with logger.below is the code sample

```
cardRegex="(\\\\b(?!59\\\\d{14})\\\\d{13,50}\\\\b)"
maskedCardString="XXXX ... XXX"
```

Above values are in a .properties file. Below staement replaces regex matches with XXXX ... XXX

```
#[payload.replaceAll(${cardRegex},${maskedCardString})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Log4j2 has a couple of ways of replacing data as it is written to the log

In a new test Mule app open up the log4j2.xml config and change the PatternLayout pattern attribute like:

`<PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %replace{%m}{(^.*?)(foo)(.*?$)}{$1bar$3}%n"  />`

So any message (%m) written to the log can have information redacted.

...orker.01] INFO  org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor - bar